# jquery ReplaceWith not working with 2 buttons

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created 2 buttons, each button will replace content based on partial views, I could load the partial view on the page when I click the button, but this works only once, for instance I clicked button-1 and loaded data, now if I click on button 2 its not working, I needed to go back to main page to click again on button-2

```
    <h3>
       <a class="btn btn-warning" id="button1"> Partial View 1</a>
    </h3> 
    <br/>
    <h4>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" id="buttton2"> Partial view 2</a>
    </h4>
   <br/> <br/>
    <div id="testsim">
    </div>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $.get('@Url.Action("partialview1", "Home")', function (data1) {
            if (data1) {
                $('#testsim').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
        });
         $('#button2').click(function () {
             $.get('@Url.Action("partialview2", "Home")', function (data2) {
                 if (data2) {
                     $('#testsim').replaceWith(data2);
                 }
        });
        });


});

</script>
```

I'm trying to achieve button clicks to toggle between two buttons, everytime button click should replace the content in div tag. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because of `replaceWith()` which replaces the element itself i.e. `outerHTML`-

```js
$(function() {
  let $html, current;
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    /* $.get('@Url.Action("partialview1", "Home")', function(data1) {
       if (data1) {
         $('#testsim').replaceWith(data);
       }
     });*/
    current = `button 1 was <em>clicked</em>`;
    $html = `<div><strong>${current}</strong></div>`;
    $('#testsim').replaceWith($html);
  });

  $('#button2').click(function() {
    /*$.get('@Url.Action("partialview2", "Home")', function(data2) {
      if (data2) {
        $('#testsim').replaceWith(data2);
      }
    });*/
    current = `button 2 was <strong>clicked</strong>`;
    $html = `<div><em>${current}</em></div>`;
    $('#testsim').replaceWith($html);
  });


});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  <a class="btn btn-warning" id="button1"> Partial View 1</a>
</h3>
<br/>
<h4>
  <a class="btn btn-warning" id="button2"> Partial view 2</a>
</h4>
<br/> <br/>
<div id="testsim" style="background: aquamarine; height: 200px">
</div>
```

As you can see that the styling of the element disappears after replacing. If you want to perform this operation then you should use `html()` which replaces only `innerHTML`-

```js
$(function() {
  let $html, current;
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    /* $.get('@Url.Action("partialview1", "Home")', function(data1) {
       if (data1) {
         $('#testsim').replaceWith(data);
       }
     });*/
    current = `button 1 was <em>clicked</em>`;
    $html = `<div><strong>${current}</strong></div>`;
    $('#testsim').html($html);
  });

  $('#button2').click(function() {
    /*$.get('@Url.Action("partialview2", "Home")', function(data2) {
      if (data2) {
        $('#testsim').replaceWith(data2);
      }
    });*/
    current = `button 2 was <strong>clicked</strong>`;
    $html = `<div><em>${current}</em></div>`;
    $('#testsim').html($html);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>
  <a class="btn btn-warning" id="button1"> Partial View 1</a>
</h3>
<br/>
<h4>
  <a class="btn btn-warning" id="button2"> Partial view 2</a>
</h4>
<br/> <br/>
<div id="testsim" style="background: aquamarine; height: 200px">
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Instead of text like 'xyz' or 'abc', how can I pass partial view in .html? (@Url.Action("Partialview", "Home")

Comment: @Maddy, the usual way. I don't know which language or framework you're using but you get the data via `AJAX`, create an `HTML` from it, store it in a `variable` and then display it. I have updated my answer to display `HTML` instead of just `strings`. If the problem still persists then try updating the tags of your question with related lang/framework

Comment: I've changed my code to Ajax, later it worked well with .html()

Comment: I'm glad, I could be of help. Happy coding. :)